# Error when trying to upload image using react-native-webview v11.0.2 in a simulator iPhone 11 on xCode 12.4

Tags: upload, webkit, xcode12, react-native-webview

When trying to upload an image to a web system, using webview in react-native v0.63.2 and react-native-webview v11.0.2 on an iPhone 11 emulator using iOS 14, I get the error on the xCode console:

2021-02-11 19:07:33.784921-0300 Ebank[2851:26809] [ProcessSuspension] 0x111cac210 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS UnboundedNetworking assertion 'WebKit uploads' for process with PID 2860, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Required client entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"UnboundedNetworking" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Required client entitlement is missing}

Emulating on Android, the upload happens normally. Any idea what it might be?

Thank you all.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? I have the same issue and it's few days of crazyness here without any sign of progress... thank you in advance 